# Not able to send second element to next line in flex display

Tags: css, flexbox

I am working on this demo. Why am I not able to send the `p` to second line in flex content?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Line One</h1>
  <br />
  <p>Line Two</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add flex-direction:column; in parent div

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `p`'s `width` to `100%` and set its parent `flex-wrap: wrap`, otherwise `h1` and `p` will shrink to fit.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Line One</h1>
  <p>Line Two</p>
</div>
```

You can also create a `.breaker` with `width: 100%` and `display: block`:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.breaker {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Line One</h1>
  <div class="breaker"></div>
  <p>Line Two</p>
</div>
```